# Teradata: Keep running the script although there are errors

Tags: teradata

I have a long script with sql statements to run on teradata. I want the script to keep running until the end and save the errors in a log file and that it will stop on every error. How can I do it?

thanks

Comment: This question is too broad for SO, but I would suggest checking out [this article](https://developer.teradata.com/blog/mtmoura/2010/04/lets-talk-about-stored-procedures) on developer.teradata.com that covers Stored Procedure Exception Handling in Teradata to get some ideas.

Comment: "keep running until the end and save the errors in a log file *and that it will stop on every error*" isn't this statement self-contradictory? You want it to keep running till the end regardless of any execution errors while logging errors or do you want it to stop on each error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Teradata SQL Assistant:
Click on Tools in the menu bar, then Options, then Query.  There is a checkbox that says "Stop query execution if an SQL error occurs"

To get the most recent error hit F11.  Otherwise, from the menu bar click Tools, then show history.  Double click on the row number on the left side of one of the history records and it will bring up a screen with the result messages for each statement.  You can also query this sort of info directly from one of the QryLog views in DBC.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I see all the errors at once without the need to double click each one of them at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Errors can be of multiple types, some can be by-passed and some cannot be. For example, with native Teradata Tools and Utilities you can make a script ignore run-time errors, or even syntax errors, but *generally* it is impossible to ignore network connectivity errors and still get remaining part of your queries executed.

Generally in such scenarios, you want to use the BTEQ tool for executing the SQL in which you can ignore the execution errors. BTEQ is a standard Teradata tool which can be downloaded from Teradata website for free and is commonly installed by users querying Teradata through plain SQL.

To create a workable BTEQ script simply copy paste all of your queries into a plain text file, separate all queries with semicolons `;` and on the very top of that plain text file add a logon statement as stated below

```
.logon Teradata_IP_Address/your_UserName,your_Password;
```

example script:

```
.logon 127.0.0.1/dbc,dbc;

/*Some sample queries. Replace these with your actual queries*/
SELECT Current_Timestamp;

CREATE TABLE My_Table (Dummy INTEGER) PRIMARY INDEX (Dummy);
```

So BTEQ got you through the execution errors. To avoid network connectivity issues, ideally you want to execute that on a server which has a constant connection to Teradata and with Teradata Tools and Utilities installed. Such a server may be called as ETL server, landing server, edge node or managed server (or something else, depending on your environment). You will definitely need login credentials to that server (if you don't already have access). Preferable commands to execute a bteq script are

Windows: `bteq < yourscriptname >routine_logfile 2>error_logfile`

Linux (bash/ksh): `nohup bteq < yourscriptname >routine_logfile 2>error_logfile &`

Make sure not to close the command prompt if you are on windows. On Linux you can close the current window or even terminate your network session with your ETL server if you use the recommended command.

If you see a warning about EOL line found at the end of your logs, just ignore it; it is because for simplicity I ignored some optional BTEQ statements which ensure cleaner exit.